# Redirect URI to application when http or https is required

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, redirect

Typically when I do an OAuth2 flow, I have a custom redirect URI to pass an access token back to my application (e.g. myapp://oauthresponse).

I have recently ran into an OAuth2 flow that requires an http or https scheme. Because of this I can't redirect back to my application. Any suggestions or tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Implement a Web API that returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: myapp://oauthresponse?......
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
```

and put the Web API at `http(s)://your-host/...`. Then register `http(s)://your-host/...` as a redirect endpoint.